# JavaScript and jQuery: Is there any PROPER onchange event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onchange

As we all know 'onchange' event will fire ONLY when the input will loose its focus.
But the web apps often requires to do something immediately if the input changes its value and without difference how those changes happens: by users keyboard, mouse or other script...
Of course I can declare a function which will fire 100 times a second and check the value of needed elements and do something if value changed.
But it looks weird: first it will take more power from users browser, second 1/100 of a second can be insufficient in some cases and so on... It is not beautifully at last!

Do you have any better ideas?

Comment: In javascript, the changes made by script will not fire any native events

Comment: Try onkeypress in your input text box. That will help for you

Comment: for catching script changes, your scripts should play nicely with each other, either publish events deliberately through some pub/sub system or provide hooks for observers to connect to.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for multiple event's to be sure

```
$('input').on("keyup input paste propertychange", function(event){
  // do stuff
});
```

Comment: @RomanMatveev .. propertychange event seem's only working on IE,,It doesn't work on other browser's

Answer (score 0):

Use `keyup` - it will fire straight away rather than when the input has lost focus:

```
$("#input").keyup(function() {

});
```

Comment: It will not work if I'd like to track changes made by another JS function :(

Answer (score 0):

On modern browsers, you should use oninput event:

```
$("input").on('input',function() {
    //code here
});
```

Comment: It's working for input made by user but isn't if I'm changing the input by JS :(

Comment: Basically, if you change value of an input programmatically using js, you should trigger handler of 'oninput' event at same time. If you cannot for some reason modify the js script changing the input value, you should have a look at observable method but it's not a good habit to use them

Comment: @RomanMatveev i think non of the events are fired, if you do a programatic change.

Comment: @roasted Thank you! But if there are many functions which could change the input?